# How to pass string argument to the python script saving quotes in it

Tags: python

I am having trouble with passing a string argument to a Python script.

I need to pass a string in this format: `"{"test_key_1": [1, 3], "test_key_2": [5]}"`

but when I am doing this:

```
test_script.py --test_arg "{"test_key_1": [1, 3], "test_key_2": [5]}"
```

I am getting this string inside the script:

```
'{test_key_1: [1, 3], test_ket_2: [5]}'
```

Why did my double quotes disappear?

I need to do `json.loads(string_argument)` after I get the argument, but it fails because of the wrong format.

Comment: Your shell is consuming the quotes before they get to your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes like this:

```
test_script.py --test_arg "{\"test_key_1\": [1, 3], \"test_key_2\": [5]}"
```

or like just change the delimiters like this:

```
test_script.py --test_arg '{"test_key_1": [1, 3], "test_key_2": [5]}'
```

Comment: OMG, right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either escape the inner quotes or use single quotes as the delimiter:

```
test_script.py --test_arg '{"test_key_1": [1, 3], "test_key_2": [5]}'
```